# How to control assets path after ng build?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-cli, arcgis-js-api

Im trying to use assets to get svg icons work on my ESRI map.
Im using Angular9 with esri js api and trying to add symbol from url.

So locally, the svg is appeared on the map but after I build the project and deploy to iis it search for the svg in a wrong location.

I'm using:
`ng build --base-href ./`

Deploy on
`Https://myserver/gis-ng/`

The page for tests and where the map should be visible:
`Https://myserver/gis-ng/api.html`

So the svg are located in `Https://myserver/gis-ng/assets/icons/*.svg`

But it search in 
`Https://myserver/assets/icons/*.svg`
Which is obviously a wrong location

Tried using --deploy-url but it didn't work.

Hope you will help me, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think that it should be `--base-href /gis-ng/`, that is why the urls are missing the "project name" `gis-ng`.